# Is it possible in mongodb to use an async function to populate the $set field?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongojs

Each document in my collection has a `status` field that needs to be updated periodically with an async api call that fetches the document's current status by its id.

For example:

```
db.items.update({}, { $set: { status: getStatusById(id?) } }, handleResult);
```

I cannot just select all ids at once as my process runs out of memory if I do that. There are over 6 million documents in the collection.

If there is no shortcut, another approach would be to step through the database 100 at a time but I'm not sure if that's the best approach here.

I am looking for something analogous to `docs.map(getStatusById)` in JS only with a mongodb collection.

`getStatusById` makes an api call to a 3rd party resource -- I need to take results from that and add to doc.

Comment: What is the implementation of the `getStatusById(id?)` method? You should be able to use the bulk API to carry out your updates in an efficient manner

Comment: It makes an api call to a 3rd party resource -- I need to take results from that and add to doc.